# %UserName% in Windows File Explorer Search Box does not work

Tags: c#, windows, windows-search, wds

I have users that have folders on a network drive that have their username part of the folder name.

How can I modify this search to work?
kind:=folder %UserName%

Note: Below works, but i need to be able to use %username% to work.

kind:=folder jsmith

If that cannot work, can I edit a saved search in notepad for jsmith, and do a find and replace with something like "System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName Kind:=folder"

It actually is my goal to make a .search-ms file that uses this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to use %USERPROFILE%  instead of %USERNAME%.

Comment: No. Another Example: I have a network share with 1000 folders. Some of these folders have my username as part of the folders name: z:\server\share\folder\001jsmith, z:\server\share\folder\002jsmith, z:\server\share\folder\003jsmith. I want to type %username% or equivalent in the search box to instantly filter to show these 3 folders.

Comment: have you tried Environment.UserName?

Comment: Typing Environment.UserName into the search box did not filter the folders with my username for me. =(